# Adding year column and reshaping data in list object in R

Tags: r

I am facing the following problem. I am using University of Delaware's air temperature data (can find here @ [http://climate.geog.udel.edu/~climate/html_pages/download.html](http://climate.geog.udel.edu/%7Eclimate/html_pages/download.html) --under the following head Terrestrial Air Temperature: 1900-2017 Gridded Monthly Time Series (V 5.01)). It gives yearly data in the fixed width format with following convention on naming the files: air_temp.1900, air_temp.1901 air_temp.1902...... air_temp.2017.

From this data I used the following codes to extract data as data frame making list of data from 2005- 15.

```
#list all files in the folder

p <- paste0("air_temp", sep= ".", 2005:2015)


#make a function to extract data from Uni_Del files
read_udel = function(p){
  d = read.fwf(p, widths=rep(8,15))
  names(d) = c("long","lat",month.abb,"mean")
  return(d)
}

#Make a list of that contains all data
read.all = lapply(p, read_udel)
```

Post this for each year data comes in the following format:

```
lat | long | jan | feb| ........Dec| Mean
```

Now I want to convert data for each year in long format using lat and long as an Id variable. But two problems which I am facing are as follows:

> 1. column for year is missing in all years data frame and I am
>    failing to figure out how can I add that to each data frame
>    corresponding to that years observation.
> 2. I don't know how can I iterate overs all the data frame contained
>    in the list to change data for each year from wide to long in one go
>    (without doing it individually one by one)

I need data in the following format for each year:

```
lat | long | year| month | air_temp
 x      y   1900     Jan     ..... (some value)
 x      y   1900     Feb     .....
 x      y   1900     March   .....
```

could someone please help me with this?
Thanks alot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a year column, I would suggest that you modify your custom function:

```
read_udel = function(p){
  d = read.fwf(p, widths=rep(8,15))
  names(d) = c("long","lat",month.abb,"mean")
  d$year <- stringi::stri_extract_all(p, regex="\\d+")
  return(d)
}
```

I could not try it, please let me know if it works

And for changing all data frames in the list from wide to long, I can imagine a sort of `lapply` coupled with your favourite reshaping function? (e.g `dplyr::pivot_longer` etc).